# Не отображается название города

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, cookie

Отображается только надпись - TechnoStore. А должно отображаться и название города.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Electromart</title>
        <!-- <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/8274996f8cf973b15814827fa281e485?family=TechnojunkW00-Regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/eshop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__container"> 
            <div class="topheader">
                <div class="topheader1">
                    <?php
                        echo $_COOKIE["city"];      
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="header__item">
                <div class="logoimage">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header__item">  
                <div class="char">
                    <div class="char1">
                        T
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="char">
                    <div class="char2">
                        e
                    </div>...
    </header>
<footer class="footer">

</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geoloc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geocode1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

geocode1.js

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({address: lat + ',' + lng}, function (results, status) {
          if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK || !results[0]) {
              return;
          }
          var result = results[0];

          var city, region, country;

          for (var i = 0; i < result.address_components.length; i++) {
              if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "locality") {
                  city = result.address_components[i];
              }
              if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "administrative_area_level_1") {
                  region = result.address_components[i];
              }
              if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "country") {
                  country = result.address_components[i];
              }

              let div = document.createElement("div");
              let text = document.createElement("p");
              text.innerHTML = '${city}, ${country}';  

              document.body.append(div);
              div.append(text);
          }

          // alert(city.long_name + ", " + region.long_name + ", " + country.short_name);

      });

    createCookie("city", city.long_name, "10");
  });

  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
      expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы уверенный, что ваша кука создаётся? попробуйте такой метод создания куки - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-cookie/642900#642900

Comment: Возможная причина в том, что при создании куки у вас пустое значение `city.long_name`  переместите `createCookie("city", city.long_name, "10");` вовнутрь `geocoder.geocode({address: lat + ',' + lng}, function (results, status) {`

Comment: @Arsen пробовал setCookie не помогло (и внутри функции geocoder.geocode)

Comment: т.е кука не создаётся? или данные пусты? проверяли, в `city.long_name` есть какие-то данные?

Comment: @Arsen 
Каким образом можно вывести переменные javascript кода (переменные city, region, country файла geocode1.js). Ведь если к этим переменным можно получить доступ в файле 

main.php (main.html), то я бы вывел на экран эти переменные и без cookie (вообще бы не использовал cookie, т.е. вообще не задавал бы этот вопрос) (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086646/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0 ).

Comment: @Arsen Или можно вывести эти переменные в js файле, а поскольку js файл 
подключается к php (html), то они и выведутся в main?

Comment: В вашем случае лучше использовать куку(или localstorage) чтобы для нового пользователя один раз вызвать `Geocoder` получить город , установить в куку и иметь доступ к данной информации на всех страницах сайта. По всей вероятности вы что то не так делаете при получении города или создании куки, попробуйте всё перепроверить.

Comment: @Arsen см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087303/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: Интерестно узнать, а что я там  должен увидеть? `text.innerHTML = `${city}, ${country}`;` ?

Comment: @Arsen см. P. S. (в самом конце вопроса) на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087303/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: А как вы решили эту задачу, могли бы дать ответ? Тоже отображается только часть и такое впечатление, что остальная часть как бы скрыта.