# Не работает вывод в javascript. Локализация ошибки

Tags: javascript, php, отладка, вывод

В коде получения названия города и записи его в куки, добавил отладочный вывод в 2 местах (для локализации ошибки на [Не отображается название города](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086764/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) ) (эти операторы не отработали)

```
alert(1)
```

и

```
        alert(city.long_name);
        alert(1);
        setCookie("city", city.long_name, "10");

        alert(city.long_name + ", " + region.long_name + ", " + country.short_name);
```

Привожу весь код ниже

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    alert(1);
    geocoder.geocode({address: lat + ',' + lng}, function (results, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK || !results[0]) {
            return;
        }
        var result = results[0];

        var city, region, country;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.address_components.length; i++) {
            if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "locality") {
                city = result.address_components[i];
            }
            if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "administrative_area_level_1") {
                region = result.address_components[i];
            }
            if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "country") {
                country = result.address_components[i];
            }


        }

                    let div = document.createElement("div");
            let text = document.createElement("p");
            text.innerHTML = '${city}, ${country}';  

            document.body.append(div);
            div.append(text);
            print_r(city);
            echo 'q';
            alert(city.long_name);
            alert(1);
            setCookie("city", city.long_name, "10");

            alert(city.long_name + ", " + region.long_name + ", " + country.short_name);

    });

  // createCookie("city", city.long_name, "10");
});

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }
  else {
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

Но у меня не вывелась 1, city, q, region.long_name, country.short_name.
 Этот код я подключил в main.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geoloc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geocode1.js"></script>
```

P. S. Расположил первый alert(1), который шел после

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

перед

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

и на экране вывелось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему то не работает код внутри

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

P.S.1 Изменил код на

```
//alert(1);

window.onload=function () {

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
alert(1);
```

Comment: я думал возможно ошибка в подключении js файла в eshop.php
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geoloc.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geocode1.js"></script>
а именно в указании пути к файлам в атрибуте src тега script (вместо /js/geocode1.js - ../js/geocode1.js или ./js/geocode.js)
однако попытки изменить атрибут src к успеху не привели

Comment: Функция написана на jquery, вы подключали эту библиотеку? Попробуйте заменить $(document).ready на ванильный аналог: window.onload = function() {

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> Но мне нужен работоспособный код, поэтому если есть другие варианты атрибута src тега script, то обязательно укажите их. И нужно ли указывать при подключении jquery библиотеки type="text/javascript" ? @letUser

Comment: По тому коду, что вижу, могу сказать, что jquery вообще не нужен. Переписать на window.onload помогло? Если нет, то надо копать глубже

Answer (score 0):

```
text.innerHTML = `${city}, ${country}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы немного неверно вставили предложенный мной ранее код.
Обратите внимание на кавычки в строке text.innerHTML.
Они должны быть ` а не '

Answer (score 0):

ssl установлен? Для работы большинства Гугл api, необходим сертификат. Так же, что с API ключём, ошибок не бьёт при инициализации?
Желательно прописать fallback на вызов Геокодера. Или в проверках, или с помощью конструкции try... catch. 
Старайтесь меньше использовать алерт, он плохо подходит для вывода объектов js, лучше подойдёт консоль.
Для начала проверьте что приходит в колбэк. Так вы сразу увидите что вам пришло, и пришло ли вообще.

```
....
geocoder.geocode({address: lat + ',' + lng}, function (results, status) {

    console.log(results, status) //<-------

        if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK || !results[0]) {
            return;
        }
....
```

Comment: вошел в инcтрументы разработчика браузера

Uncaught Syntax Error: geoloc.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at window.onload (geocode1.js:7) : geocode1.js:7

Comment: Как я понял  из https://enterprise.arcgis.com/ru/web-adaptor/10.3/install/iis/enable-https-on-your-web-server-server-.htm 
 сертификат ssl устанавливается в Управлении компьютером в Windows 
Не понятно откуда панель Подключения берется, как до нее добраться

Comment: Ой, ну тут сложно в двух словах объяснить. А с учётом того что вам отбивает - google is not defined - сначала нужно подключить gmaps на страницу, а затем решать все ошибки по мере поступления)

Comment: На сертификат пока не обращайте внимания. Вам сам Гугл нужно запустить. Вы скрипт подключили?

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>.  Это подключение Гугл мапс api. Но лучше прочесть в документации что с ним делать и как работать. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=ru.     Вам не нужно отдельное подключение геодекодера. Этим скриптом поставляются все доступные апи